# Clear all Filters/Sort/Pagination on a DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

Seems like a simple task but I couldn't find an easy way to do it.

The user tweaks a "State" (filters/sorts/pagination) of a DataTable, and I need to clear it and reset to the original blank slate, e.g. on a click of a custom button. That should erase all filters/sorts/pagination set by the user.

The only way I found is to `destroy` and then re-initalize. But I don't like this solution because it re-fetches data. My data's already available and I just need a quick reset of the user's state changes back to blank.

```
var activeRequestsTable = $('#activeRequestsTable').DataTable();
activeRequestsTable.state.clear();
activeRequestsTable.destroy();
    $('#activeRequestsTable').DataTable({
           "ajax": {
            url: myUrl,
            dataSrc: 'activeRequests',
            type: 'POST',
            //etc.
        }
    },
    "columns": [ .. ]
    });
```

Note that the below is a simple example without AJAX -- it just uses a static DOM for simplicity. But the button should still clear everything efficiently. I added it here in case you want something to play with. But it shouldn't be a re-creation of the DataTable (which in my case would be AJAX-based) because that's a performance penalty. I'm looking for something quick and client-side.

```js
$('#example').DataTable();
```

```css
.display {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<button id="clear">Clear all Filters/Sort/Pagination</button><br/><br/>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009/04/10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
       </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got the response on the DataTables forum,

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/53766/how-to-clear-all-filter-sorts-pagination-without-reinitializing-the-table-from-scratch#latest

No, no easy way to reset the state without destroying/re-initializing:

> No, there's no, I'm afraid to say - the only guaranteed way is to
>   `destroy()` and reinitialise, but that would refetch data as you said.
>   You can clear searches and pagination easily with `search()` and `page()`
>   respectively, but the ordering is a pickle as clearing it with `order()`
>   can leave residue of previous searches...
>
> Cheers,

So it looks like even though I could reset Filter & Pagination, the Sort is harder to reset.

Bottom line: the only way to reset the state is to destroy & re-initialize from scratch.